# Unable to retrieve data from a SQLite database & display on QT GUI

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I'm trying to create a login system whereby if a person logs in, it should display their name on the Qt GUI that follows the login GUI.

I've tried using the code below however, the label is just blank, so I'm assuming the issue is from the database. All help will be appreciated, thank you.

```cpp
#include "TaxiCoZa.h"

TaxiCoZa::TaxiCoZa(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent) {   
    ui.setupUi(this);
    Connection x;
    isConnected(x)
};

void TaxiCoZa::on_loginButton_clicked() {
    emailInput = ui.emailEdit1->text();
    passwordInput = ui.passwordEdit1->text();
    Connection y;
    QSqlQuery query;
    
    query.prepare("SELECT * FROM riders WHERE email='" + emailInput + "' and password='" + passwordInput + "'");
    
    if (query.exec()) {
        int count = 0;
        
        while (query.next()) {
            count++;
        }
        // scenario for the correct password
        if (count == 1) {
            QString name;
            
            QSqlQuery query2;
            
            query2.prepare("SELECT (name) FROM riders WHERE email='" + emailInput + "' and password='" + passwordInput + "'");
            query2.exec();
            
            while (query.next())
            {
                name = query2.value(0).toString();
                break;
            }
            
            y.connClose();
            this->hide();
            Book b;
            b.setGreetingLabel("Hello, " + name);
            b.exec();   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both answers below are not correct (event he first one shows you how to avoid sql injection). You're retrieving the whole data with QSqlQuery::next() and try to read it again later on but the next() can't return anything anymore since you already read all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by using the first() function from the QSqlQuery class

Kindly see the code below for changes

```
void TaxiCoZa::on_loginButton_clicked() {
QString emailInput = ui.emailEdit1->text();
QString passwordInput = ui.passwordEdit1->text();

QSqlQuery query;

query.prepare("SELECT * FROM riders WHERE email='" + emailInput + "' and password='" + passwordInput + "'");

if (query.exec()) {
    int count = 0;

    while (query.next()) {
        count++;
    }

    if (count == 1) {
        query.first(); // change made here
        QString name = query.value(1).toString();
        y.connClose();
        this->hide();
        
        Book b;
        b.setGreetingLabel("Hello, " + name);
        b.exec();
    }
    else if (count > 1) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "DUPLICATE");
    }
    else{
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "INCORRECT EMAIL OR PASSWORD ENTERED!!!");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

your `query.prepare("Select ...")` doesn't seem to be correctly written.
Try this;

```
query.prepare("SELECT * FROM riders WHERE email= 'emailInput' and password='passwordInput'");
```

Also, do the same changes on the second query. Follow that format.

Comment: that part is correct, that's for the login part and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run two queries within each other the way you have done it. In your first query, `SELECT (name)` directly, don't run another query. And make sure `name` exists in your SQLite db.

If you must run two queries try; `mysql_query()` and `mysql_real_query()`
But still you cannot run two (or more) statements simultaneously in one
connection. It's impossible. You might be able to *send* multiple statements
at once but it's highly discouraged. But even in that case the
statements will be executed one after the other.

Your best bet, try to get the `name` with your first query.

Comment: Are those really two separate answers? If not, please use the edit button to update your current answer.